# Parse INI from external link

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I have this code:

```
$url = parse_ini_file(file('http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=' . $id), true);
print_r($url['playlist']);
```

That's a `.pls` file, which I'm trying to parse as an array. It's not working – why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work, because `parse_ini_file()` accepts filename as the first parameter, not the array returned by `file()` call. If `parse_ini_file` supports URL wrappers, you could use:

```
$url = parse_ini_file('http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=' . $id, true);
print_r($url['playlist']);
```

Otherwise you would be left with:

```
$url = parse_ini_string(file_get_contents('http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id='.$id, TRUE));
print_r($url['playlist']);
```

Comment: I already tried all of that but it still doesn't work. my output is just empty. tried to print_r $url only, it should output 'Array', but nothing...

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` to display all keys in the array. Could be case mismatch... Also if you could provide us with real `$id`, it could help.

Comment: Okay var_dump does work. Im just not getting access to an entry.

Comment: Okay i got it. print_r didnt work with array variables. dont know why. now did it with echo. Thank you. parse_ini_string was the solution!